# Not getting DNS record using org.xbill.DNS lib

Tags: java, dns, dnsjava

I have written following code to get MX record for any Domain, here google.com

```
public class DNSRec {
public static void main(String... args) 
{
    try{
        Record [] records = new Lookup("http://www.google.com", Type.NS).run();
        for (int i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
            NSRecord ns = (NSRecord) records[i];
            System.out.println("Nameserver " + ns.getTarget());
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());
    }
}}
```

> **Output**: Exception: null

I have used **org.xbill.DNS** lib.

**What is going wrong in above code ?**

**Should i use this library or there is any other better way to get DNS records?**

Small example ;) most welcome :)  . . . . Your response will be greatly appreciated

My internet connection is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Two things are wrong here:

1. The code looks up MX records and then tries to cast the result to a NSRecord.
2. You should not pass the protocol into the `Lookup` class constructor. You are doing a Nameserver lookup for a **domain** not a URL. Hence you should use `google.com` instead of `http://www.google.com`

Give this a go:

```
public class DNSRec {
public static void main(String... args) 
{
    try{
        Lookup lookup = new Lookup("google.com", Type.NS);
        Record[] records = lookup.run();

        for (int i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
            NSRecord ns = (NSRecord) records[i];
            System.out.println("Nameserver " + ns.getTarget());
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());
    }
}}
```

Comment: Thank you Tom for reply. I tried NS also, still it is showing same output.   :(

Comment: yes i have tried in both ways but same output...Have you tried it?

Comment: I have - it works fine for me. Get the following console output: Nameserver ns1.google.com.
Nameserver ns3.google.com.
Nameserver ns4.google.com.
Nameserver ns2.google.com.

Comment: great. But not working for me :(   I have tried it with javax.naming.directory but the code is not understandable by me, that is why i go with org.xbill.DNS lib. Have you ever use javax.naming.directory. Thanks for reply :)